# Regular expression to match d o u b l e s p a c e text inside normal text

Tags: regex

I have some text like

```
 proposed that the U n i o n  D i s u n i o n was there
```

so a space between every char of part of a normal string.

Expected output is a match on just "U n i o n   D i s u n i o n". The double spaced part.

I want a regular expression that matches the double space portion only.
`[a-zA-Z](?=\s)\s` matches a single part ('U '), but I can't see how to extend it.

Comment: Which tool/language?

Comment: What is your expected match from this string?

Comment: Perl/Python compatible reg. exp.

Comment: Expected output is a match on just "U n i o n  D i s u n i o n". The double spaced part.

Comment: What did you try already? You said it only matches a single portion, so what does yours return? Perhaps you could edit your question to include the regular expression that's not working

Comment: How does this work for you: [`/(?:\b[a-z]\s)+/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/hQ2dI6/1)

Comment: @Sam: Given that there are two whitespace characters between `Union` and `Disunion`, that should probably be a `\s+` in your regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<!\w)(?:\w\s+(?=\w\s))+\w
```

should do the job.

```
(?<!\w) # assert there aren't 2 word characters in a row
(?:
    \w\s+ # match a word character and whitespace...
    (?=\w\s) # if there's another word character and a space
)+ # any number of times.
\w # finally match the last word character (but no space)
```

Comment: +1, but I would *consider* using `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` instead of `(?<!\w)` to keep the same mindset (we are looking for a letter followed by a space, not a letter followed by a non-letter). For instance: "a b c" would be matched in "#a b c" but not "a b c#". Also, you positive look head in the repeated group should be `(?=\w(?:\s|$))` so it doesn't fail at the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703229/sam)'s idea in the comment, and the fact that `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` is equivalent to `(?!\S)`, we can simplify the regex to:

```
(?<!\S)\w(?: +\w)+(?!\S)
```

I also switch up `(token separator)* token` form in Rawing's answer to the preferred form `token (separator token)*`, which does slightly less backtracking on backtracking engines.

The `\s+` in the middle is switched to  `+` to only allow space (U+0020). Depending on the support, `\h+` might be more appropriate here. I don't think you want to match across lines.